# How to check last added item is a folder or not in Sharepoint event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-2010, eventreceiver

Inside my ItemAdded function I want to check the last added item is a folde or not.  How to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ClassName : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        bool isFolder = (properties.ListItem.Folder != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check this and let you know.  The code which I used to create folders in my event receiver is not working. Checking with that now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676531/create-a-folder-in-document-library-using-sharepoint-event-receiver

Comment: how to get the folder name ? i want to fetch the folder name and fetch the items inside the folder and apply view permissions on those items

Comment: @SaMolPP I suggest you post it as a new question. I haven't been working with SharePoint for years now, so I won't be able to help here.